# How to add stroke on outside of TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

### Any ideas, code snippets are welcome!

I have created a `CustomTextView` class that extends `AppCompatTextView` and I did this to add **stroke** support to boring `TextView`. The problem is, `Paint.Style.STROKE` adds stroke on the inside of `TextView`. There should be something which allows us to choose between outer-stroke and inner-stroke.
P.S: I can share the complete `CustomTextView` class if needed, not a big deal.

- What we currently have:
  [image]
- What we want to achieve:
  [image]

This is the `onDraw` method from our `CustomTextView` which is used to add stroke to textView.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(_strokeWidth > 0) {
            //set paint to fill mode
            Paint p = getPaint();
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            //draw the fill part of text
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            //save the text color
            int currentTextColor = getCurrentTextColor();
            //set paint to stroke mode and specify
            //stroke color and width
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p.setStrokeWidth(_strokeWidth);
            setTextColor(_strokeColor);
            //draw text stroke
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            //revert the color back to the one
            //initially specified
            setTextColor(currentTextColor);
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try replacing `p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);` with `p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);`

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal it will only get it worse. We need to use Paint.Style.FILL first in order to make text filled with desired "textColor", otherwise text will be transparent.

Comment: Reverse the drawing of the text and outline: Draw the outline first then the text.

Comment: I am not very sure as I have not used it but u can try this library -> `https://github.com/Maggie-Wan/StrokeTextView`

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal this library seems to be helpful. I'll try this with modifications for custom use.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal as I said earlier it seems to be helpful, but I cannot change stroke values on runtime. I've tried but it doesn't. Can you suggest something, or can you try modifying this library's code?

Comment: try this -> `https://github.com/melihaksoy/StrokedTextView`

Comment: @Cheticamp it messes up the textView. Try this on your own and you'll get the idea.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal the library you recommended later, is coded in Kotlin. I'll only be able to use it as a library and I won't be able to use it's custom class which he extended with TextView. If I would be able to use is custom textView class, I'd be able to modify it's function to meet my needs. I hope I'm being clear

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal if it was coded in Java like the earlier library, then I might use it's code after modifications. But I'm not that good at Kotlin yet.

Comment: then try this -.> `https://github.com/HamCheeseDev/OutlinedTextView` I tried it. It also allows you to change stroke width, color etc on runtime

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions and your time dear , I've found helpful solution by @Cheticamp and I'm using that now. Cheers Pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following draws the outline of the characters in a *TextView* but takes care to clip out the characters themselves so they are not drawn over.

**OutlineTextView.java**

```
public class OutlineTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private final Paint mOutlinePaint = new Paint();
    private final Path mOutlinePath = new Path();
    private float mStrokeWidth = 0f;

    public OutlineTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OutlineTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OutlineTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mOutlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(0f);
        mOutlinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mOutlinePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        float xOffset = getLayout().getLineLeft(0) + getPaddingLeft();
        float baseline = getLayout().getLineBaseline(0) + getPaddingTop();
        getPaint().getTextPath(getText().toString(), 0, getText().length(), xOffset, baseline, mOutlinePath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mStrokeWidth > 0) {
            canvas.save();
            // The following insures that we don't draw inside the characters.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                canvas.clipPath(mOutlinePath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
            } else {
                canvas.clipOutPath(mOutlinePath);
            }
            canvas.drawPath(mOutlinePath, mOutlinePaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(Float strokeWidth) {
        mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        mOutlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

[image]